# How can I prevent a specific group from printing a certian document?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, folder, printing, irm

I have a SharePoint site with few folders,
each folder has users with permission to edit it 
and users with permission to read only.
I want that the users with the 'Read Only' permission 
won't be able to print the documents in the folder.

I have heard of IRM, but is it good for permissions by groups?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot block users from printing using only Sharepoint. You need to use IRM (which is separate server/software). IRM is good to set Information policies per groups, user location even device is connecting from different vendors have different features so you would have to compare offering based on your requirements/budget.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint restriction take place at *file level*, once the file is obtained somehow, there is nothing SP can do to restrict operation at *application level*.

[Active Directory Rights Management Services (AD RMS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831364.aspx) for on-premise scenarios and [Azure Rights Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj585026.aspx) are currently offered by MS and fully supported by SharePoint & Office apps.

The best part of RMS is that even printscreening could be turned off.

Alternatively, *PDF* offers some kind of serverless operations restriction - password based. I've seen the requirement similar to yours been implemented thru converting DOCX to print-protected PDF inside SharePoint workflow.

Setting up AD RMS is relatively easy, but requires some DR planning because losing the service forever could make protected documents unopenable forever. Also, AFAIK there are some licensing requirements.